# ¿Por qué se cierra mi aplicación inesperadamente en Windows 8.1?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, aplicación-web

He instalado en mi tablet Windows 8.1 una aplicación AngularJs creada por mi en Visual Studio 2013. Toda la aplicación son html y js. La aplicación se cierra inesperadamente de manera aleatoria a veces cambia de pantalla a veces falla al hacer click en un botón...

Lo único que he conseguido es del Visor de eventos de Windows el siguiente error:

```
Firma del problema:
P1: d408d50f-b039-4e73-8c2d-d5f6564a50cd_1.0.0.2_neutral__18y3aj4fc2r50
P2: praid:App
P3: 6.3.9600.17031
P4: 53085927
P5: MSHTML.dll
P6: 11.0.9600.17924
P7: 5595a0f4
P8: c0000005
P9: 00000000000c587f
P10

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-25T14:18:11.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3436</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>TEMP5J7T7Z1.esteve.es</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>MoAppCrash</Data>
    <Data>No disponible</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>d408d50f-b039-4e73-8c2d-d5f6564a50cd_1.0.0.2_neutral__18y3aj4fc2r50</Data>
    <Data>praid:App</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.17031</Data>
    <Data>53085927</Data>
    <Data>MSHTML.dll</Data>
    <Data>11.0.9600.17924</Data>
    <Data>5595a0f4</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00000000000c587f</Data>
    <Data>
</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>5422af7a-b98f-11e7-827e-7c7a9165f206</Data>
    <Data>4100</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a entender un poco mejor qué está fallando le estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Puede hacer que tu aplicación muestre un mensaje con el error completo o que lo escriba en alguna parte (un archivo de texto), por ejemplo?. Perdona la pregunta, pero, ¿qué tiene que ver el `visor de eventos de Windows`?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, dado que solo veo que la aplicación se cierra inesperadamente y no sé donde visualizar la consola javascript de mi aplicación o los logs de mi aplicación (Antes los miraba a través del debug de Visual Studio pero ahora ya la he instalado en Windows) he ido al visor de eventos donde me ha aparecido el error que he puesto. Es todo lo que estoy pudiendo ver sobre el error.

Comment: Rinsky, si la pregunta no tiene el código *no todo el proyecto, solo el fragmento(s) de código que tenga fallos* y la descripción de los errores que tengas es muy difícil que alguien te brinde una respuesta completa. MI sugerencia es; [edit] tu pregunta con mas información "código, errores", explica qué hace tu aplicación y, honestamente: revisa tu código, modifícalo para depurar tu programa paso a paso. Suerte.